# How to skip output in linux rpl?

Tags: linux, bash

I have got command in bash script:

```
sudo rpl -iqR 'foo' 'bar' /usr/share/project > /dev/nul
```

It gives me output:

```
Replacing "foo" with "bar" (ignoring case) (partial words matched)
```

But I need to see nothing in output. How I can do that and why it display something with -q flag too?

> /dev/nul don't helps too. What I neet to do?

Comment: The path is `/dev/null`. That doesn't change things here much (but might mean you created a `/dev/nul` file. Does `> /dev/null 2>&1` hide the output?

Comment: @EtanReisner - it helps, thank you. Write it as answer and I will check it as solving answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `> /dev/null` (note the two `l`s there, `/dev/nul` is not a device so check and make sure you didn't create a `/dev/nul` file by accident) isn't silencing the output then it is most likely being sent to standard error instead of standard output (which is slightly odd).

If that's the case then using either

```
sudo rpl -iqR 'foo' 'bar' /usr/share/project > /dev/null 2>&1
```

or

```
sudo rpl -iqR 'foo' 'bar' /usr/share/project &> /dev/null
```

should work to silence it.

That being said that shouldn't be necessary and I have to wonder what (if anything) the `-q` option is silencing.

This tool might be more trouble then it is worth.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ sudo rpl -iqR 'foo' 'bar' /usr/share/project &> /dev/null
```

You might as well ommit -q option in this case.